# Angular 1.xx and Firebase : Adding Subfolder or multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am very new to Angular and programming and making a simple web app.

[Data structure in Firebase will be just as in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kri3h.png)

I am able to create topics and display them on firebase console, however I cannot add lists under each topic as in the data structure image. Editing and deleting topics work as well.

admin.js:

```
.controller('AdminCtrl', ['$scope', '$firebase', '$firebaseArray', '$firebaseObject', '$routeParams', function($scope, $firebase, $firebaseArray, $firebaseObject, $routeParams) {

$scope.id = $routeParams.id;

var ref = firebase.database().ref().child('topics');
$scope.topics = $firebaseArray(ref);

$scope.addTopic = function() {
    $scope.topics.$add({
        title: $scope.topic.title,
        curator: $scope.topic.curator,

    });
};

$scope.addList = function(id) {
    //i dont know how to add lists under each topic element.

};

$scope.deleteCnf = function(topic) {
    $scope.deleteTopic = topic;
};

$scope.deletePost = function(deleteTopic) {
    $scope.topics.$remove(deleteTopic);
};


$scope.editTopic = function(id) {
    var ref = firebase.database().ref().child('topics/' + id);
    $scope.editTopicData = $firebaseObject(ref);
};

$scope.updateTopic = function(id) {
    var ref = firebase.database().ref().child('topics/' + id);
    ref.update({
        title: $scope.editTopicData.title,
        curator: $scope.editTopicData.curator
    }).then(function(ref) {
        $('#editModal').modal('hide');
    }, function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    })
};
}]);
```

Thanks!